# Access denied error in codeigniter url is having index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I am having issue which is may be related to `.htaccess` or php configuration of ubuntu. I have tried lot to find out solution but feels helpless so, at last i decided to post a question here. May be my question is silly or may i am making mistake on very normal configuration point but at last i hope my question will helps me to find out a solution with all yours blessings..

Please, support me to find out way for my issue.

My issue is when i am opening url without having `index.php` in url it gives output success but once i put `index.php` in url it gives only "Access Denied" in response.

### Example

> It gives me "Access Denied" in response

[It gives access denied](http://devngtp.56-north.com/index.php/company-management/change-company-parameters/CMPNY_PARAM_DEFINED)

> It working fine but my all url change took longer time to change

[It's working fine](http://devngtp.56-north.com/company-management/change-company-parameters/CMPNY_PARAM_DEFINED)

## *MY `.htaccess`*

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv CI_ENV development
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /CodeIgniter_2.0.3

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Enable access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|files|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

</IfModule>
#Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I can't find way to come out from this issue. your help will be appreciated

Thanks for visiting...

Answer (score 0):

try to put these on your .htaccess
i always use it on apache server and it works

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: anyway, i could access  
http://devngtp.56-north.com/index.php/  
and  
http://devngtp.56-north.com/index.php/forgot-password

please recheck the question